# 2nd server in RabbitMQ cluster not participating, shows no uptime

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a two server RabbitMQ cluster behind a load balancer, but right now only the first nodes seems to be fielding traffic.

When I do:

```
> rabbitmqadmin list nodes name type running uptime 

+----------------------+------+---------+------------+
|         name         | type | running |   uptime   |
+----------------------+------+---------+------------+  
| rabbit@n2-rabbitmq-1 | disc | True    | 3899164848 |
| rabbit@n2-rabbitmq-2 | disc | True    |            |
+----------------------+------+---------+------------+
```

The second node shows no uptime.  A cluster_status shows:

```
> sudo rabbitmqctl cluster_status
```

Cluster status of node 'rabbit@n2-rabbitmq-1' ...
[{nodes,[{disc,['rabbit@n2-rabbitmq-1','rabbit@n2-rabbitmq-2']}]},
 {running_nodes,['rabbit@n2-rabbitmq-2','rabbit@n2-rabbitmq-1']},
 {cluster_name,<<"rabbit@n2-rabbitmq-1">>},
 {partitions,[]}]
...done.

What am I doing wrong or what should I look for?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for some reasons, one of your node went down and when it's up again, it does not sync with the 'master' node( which is the one running). To do so, set in the configuration file, **/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config** :

```
{cluster_partition_handling, autoheal}
```

I recommend that you should be using web management plugin for better observation:

```
$ rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

From the main (overview) page, you could see the status of your nodes in the cluster(connected, partitioned ...)

Anyway you'd better show your procedure of configuring (every step) your cluster with more information. If my above guess is wrong, please show me some information you get from the web interface.